# Unable to get JSON Serialization to work and also ContentNegotiation imports

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am using kotlin to code and this is the code I have :

```
package com.example.prosubscriberapp

import RecommendationService
import io.ktor.server.application.Application


import io.ktor.server.routing.routing
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.routes.*
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.service.*
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.server.application.install
import io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import recommendationRoutes

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.proSubscriberApp() {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }

    // Initialize services
    val userService = UserService()
    val planService = PlanService()
    val recommendationService = RecommendationService()
    val subscriptionService = SubscriptionService()
    val transactionService = TransactionService()

    // Configure routes
    routing {
        userRoutes(userService)
        planRoutes(planService)
        recommendationRoutes(recommendationService)
        subscriptionRoutes(subscriptionService)
        transactionRoutes(transactionService)
    }
}
```

however none of the imports work and I know it is because of some contradiction or something in my gradle files but I dont know which and I dont know how to fix it.I am new to kotlin so I am trying to slowly get a grasp of it.This is my project level gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1")
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.1" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.22"
}
```

and this is my module level:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.prosubscriberapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.prosubscriberapp"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

val exposedLibraryVersion: String by project
val h2LibraryVersion: String by project

dependencies {...}
```

If i dont include apply false in my project level , the files dont even sync and I dont know why.This is the error
Build file 'C:\Users\haroo\AndroidStudioProjects\ProSubscriberApp\build.gradle.kts' line: 7

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.9.22']

> Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'.
> Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name.

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.9.22']
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:222)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:204)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyLegacyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:157)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$300(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:60)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1$1.lambda$addLegacy$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:113)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:142)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:142)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:48)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:220)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:391)
  at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:523)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.kt:218)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator.evaluate(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:121)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:51)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:48)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:35)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
  at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:395)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:413)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:394)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:46)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:27)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:395)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:394)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:782)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:156)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$2(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$10(StateTransitionController.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:195)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:369)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:42)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:65)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
  at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:209)
  at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
  at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withProjectsConfigured$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:130)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:132)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:128)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withProjectsConfigured(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:130)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:57)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.lambda$locateBuilderForTarget$0(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withToolingModels(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:278)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.withToolingModels(AbstractBuildState.java:140)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForDefaultTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:68)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getTarget(DefaultBuildController.java:157)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:101)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:66)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:126)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:43)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:74)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:58)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:173)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:146)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyLegacyPlugin$2(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:159)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:199)
  ... 190 more
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ExtensionsStorage.add(ExtensionsStorage.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.add(DefaultConvention.java:136)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.addWithDefaultPublicType(DefaultConvention.java:228)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.create(DefaultConvention.java:142)
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinProjectExtensionKt.createKotlinExtension(KotlinProjectExtension.kt:42)
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:251)
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper.apply(PluginWrappers.kt:27)
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper.apply(PluginWrappers.kt:19)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:187)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:282)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:167)
  at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:166)
  ... 193 more

Comment: What error exactly are you getting? Please also share all the dependencies you have.

Comment: I have added the error but i cant add the dependencies as it is over the character limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

To fix your problems I suspect that you should, at least as a start:

1. Choose only one version for the Kotlin plugins you are using,
2. Remove the Kotlin JVM plugin, and
3. Apply the Kotlin serialization plugin in your Android subproject.

#### Some more background

To say more:

- The plugins `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")`, `kotlin("jvm")` and `kotlin("plugin.serialization")` all follow the same Kotlin versioning system. In other words, only use these plugins together with the same version number.
- You seem a bit confused over where to apply plugins. You have a Gradle [multiproject project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html), which does a separate build for (a) the root project, and (b) each subproject of the build. These correspond to folders and `build.gradle.kts` files in those folders. Only apply a plugin in a subproject where you want to use that plugin.
- You have applied the Kotlin JVM and serialization plugins in the root `build.gradle.kts` file. You could write Kotlin code in that way (and place the code in the `rootProject/src/main/kotlin` folder, but that would be unusual in a multiproject project. I doubt you are trying to do that.
- I doubt that you want a Kotlin JVM project as well as Kotlin Android project. You don't need both of these in one subproject: they are very similar and the first allows Kotlin code to be built for a regular JVM target whilst the latter for an Android target. If you writing Android code, go to your Android subproject folder and write code in its `src/main/kotlin` folder. You already have the Kotlin Android plugin applied there.
- Also put the Kotlin serialization plugin in the subproject that needs it. I suspect you want this in your Android subproject as well.
- When you add a plugin to the `plugins` block with `apply false`, what you are telling Gradle is: "add the JAR this plugin is in to the build classpath so that I can apply it in subprojects". This is so only one instance of the plugin classes is loaded. Such plugins must be applied in whichever subproject needs them. (Actually the Kotlin JVM and Kotlin Android plugins come from the same JAR, so you don't need to do `apply false` with both: but then I suspect you don't want the JVM plugin at all.)